# Extent Report Spark Disregards Line Feed (New Line)

Tags: testing, testng, extentreports

I added `Extent Report 5` to tests and attached spark reporter to it, all in all it looks good, however I take `result.getThrowable().getMessage()` and it does not apply `\n\r` or `\n` in resulting index.html.

I know that it happens somewhere after flush is called, since in log list it still have the correct string with all characters. Also, if I send to `fail()` method `getThrowable()` itself it will be written correctly, but it have unnessessary data - **exception** and **stack trace**.

For reference my spark-config file looks like this:

```
{
  "documentTitle": "Extent Reports Title",
  "encoding": "utf-8",
  "js": "",
  "offlineMode": true,
  "protocol": "HTTPS",
  "reportName": "ExtentReportsName",
  "timelineEnabled": false,
  "timeStampFormat": "MMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss",
  "theme": "dark"
}
```

[image: log have no new line]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only other way I know is to send your input wrapped in `<pre></pre>` tags.

You can use the below technique which will keep your formatting intact.

```
test.fail(result.getThrowable());
```

Comment: Thanks, I am using getThrowable(), I just dont need exception or stack trace.

Comment: The only other way I know is to send your input wrapped in <pre></pre> tags.